# disable two startup logos on android devices startup

Tags: boot-animation

There are **two** logos on my android device(s) showing while `loading device`.

How to remove them showing?

- First one is general android logo
- Second one is vendor specific.

I need either of them to be  disabled, **without** going to change them.

There has to be some option for this.

Comment: It would be important to know what device and ROM you are on. Certain ROMs have it built-in natively to disable boot animations.

Answer (score 3):

You need root and a root explorer like [ES File Explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.estrongs.android.pop). Go to system/media/ and delete or rename the file bootani.qmg if you want to get rid of the Android animation.

The vendor one should be named like samsungani.qmg or htcani.qmg.

Comment: What about the carrier's animation? Where is that located?

Comment: Mine was named  bootanimation.zip  at system/media. It was a zip file with folders containing jpg files to render in sequence. Also in the zip file was a text file saying how to process.

Answer (score 0):

I know this i had a galaxy ring which i rooted and found an app which accesed the dial codes from that device and i dialed it from the device dialer and voila i was able to choose from the 3 different companies boost,sprint,verizon or none at all just boots up as android im not a tech guy  I know a lil but that worked

Answer (score -1):

You can't change or remove them. Only way to do it is by installing custom ROM; which will inturn invalidate any warranty you have on the phone.

Comment: You don't need a custom ROM in order to change or remove the boot animation.